# Qual è il significato di "veleggiante" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia della bambina perduta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Avevo visto negli anni l’avvento della nuova stazione ferroviaria, il fiacco svettare del grattacielo di via Novara, i **veleggianti** edifici di Scampia, il proliferare di costruzioni altissime e splendenti sopra il pietrame grigio dell’Arenaccia, di via Taddeo da Sessa, di piazza Nazionale.

Ho trovato il significato di "veleggiare" in parecchi dizionari e ho visto che può significare "navigare" o "volare", ma non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "i veleggianti edifici" nel passaggio precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Credo che in questo caso l'autore stia facendo una sorta di simitudine fra i grattacieli (o gli edifici) e le vele di un'imbarcazione. Le vele, infatti, si trovano spesso in posizione molto elevata rispetto allo scafo, di solito in cima all'albero maestro. L'imbarcazione, in questo modo, è come se "tagliasse" il cielo grazie alle proprie vele, così come gli edifici nel brano

Comment: L'interpretazione mi sembra corretta; aggiungo che i palazzi di Scampia vengono proprio chiamati comunemente "vele" per la loro forma triangolare (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vele_di_Scampia)

Comment: Il tuo discorso è convincente, @brainplot, ma, giusto per essere precisi, non è che le vele siano “in cima all'albero maestro” (o, meglio, di maestra), ma per tutta la sua altezza: http://www.mitidelmare.it/FOTO%20GRANDI/Le_vele/Alberatura_di_un_veliero.jpg

Comment: Ti ringrazio per avermi corretto, @DaG. Non sono un esperto di barche :)

Comment: Interessante, @RiccardoDeContardi, questo non lo sapevo.

Comment: L'aggiunta di @RiccardoDeContardi credo sia molto appropriata. È molto probabile che Elena Ferrante voglia far riferimento al nome con cui sono noti quegli edifici di Scampia.

Comment: @Charo, **veleggianti** grammaticalmente cosa sia e da dove deriva è chiaro, idem per le interpretazioni che danno anche. Tuttavia rimangono interpretazioni e bisogna chiedere all´autore del libro per capire il senso che vuole dare. Sono del parere, intepretazione questa come quella dopo anche, che E. Ferrante gioca con le parole in modo astuto e in base al contesto del capitolo o della parte di esso che non hai scritto purtroppo, e non è il primo post di questo tipo, l´autore inizia con un input, poco dopo apre una parentesi quasi, e leggendo dopo ancora ritorna/prosegue con l´input.

Comment: Leggendo abbastanza e due o tre volte alcuni parti che comprendono la tua citazione, e ti parlo di uno che non conosce le citate **vele di Scampia**, pensai ad edifici/palazzi architettonicamente **a vela** (nulla di nuovo, googla un po per vedere e noterai la somiglianza o il rimando a certe architetture anche moderne), usare peró **veleggianti** sottointende un´azione da parte di questi edifici, un´azione che non puó essere altro che intesa in senso letterario o con uso di sinonimi, io pensai subito ad un uso figurato del  modo di dire **drizzare/innalzare le vele**,

Comment: azione degli edifici/palazzi, **a vela**, stessi in Scampia, ai quali l´autore fa riferimento. Il senso di quello che vuole dire viene subito dopo, tuttavia è polemico giá poiché non fa riferimento preciso "verso cosa" veleggiano/drizzano o innalzano le vele questi [...](input)Sono andata via da Napoli definitivamente nel 1995, (parentesi) quando tutti dicevano che la città stava risorgendo. Ma ormai credevo poco alle sue *resurrezioni*. Avevo visto negli anni l’avvento della nuova stazione ferroviaria, il fiacco svettare del grattacielo di via Novara,

Comment: i veleggianti edifici di Scampia, il proliferare di *costruzioni altissime e splendenti* sopra il pietrame grigio dell’Arenaccia, di via Taddeo da Sessa, di piazza Nazionale. *Quegli edifici*, immaginati in Francia o in Giappone e sorti tra Ponticelli e Poggioreale con la solita lentezza guasta, *subito*, a velocità sostenuta, *avevano perso ogni fulgore e si erano mutati in tane per disperati*.Sicché quale *resurrezione?*

Comment: Era solo cipria della modernità spruzzata a casaccio, e in maniera sbruffona, sopra la faccia corrotta della città. Ogni volta succedeva così. Il trucco della rinascenza accendeva speranze e poi si spaccava, diventava crosta sopra croste antiche. (ritorno all input)Perciò, proprio mentre correva l’obbligo di restare in città a sostenere il risanamento sotto la guida dell’ex Partito comunista, io mi decisi a partire per Torino [...].

Comment: **drizzare/innalzare le vele** è verso un qualcosa, quel qualcosa che nel libro non è *modernitá, resurrezione* o simile ma *tana per disperati*,*non rinascenza*,..., una dura critica insomma non tanto all´architettura a vela degli edifici quanto ad altro...

Comment: Va bene, @mle, per me tutto questo non era così evidente. Ricorda che non sono italiana, ma cerco d'imparare l'italiano, e per me il verbo "veleggiare" era del tutto sconosciuto... :(

Comment: la mia è solo una interpretazione, mai usato e letto o sentito in tutta la mia vita il verbo "veleggiare" o da questo il participio "veleggiante", tuttavia era semplice poiché tra dizionario e spiegazione dell´autore era chiaro il senso (almeno per me)

Comment: @mle: Lo sai che (fino a prova contraria) Elena Ferrante è una donna, e quindi un'“autrice”, non un “autore”?

Comment: @DaG, nel scrivere non pensai al genere usando "autore" in senso assoluto, ed errato non è!

Answer (score 1):

"I veleggianti edifici di Scampia" si riferisce al fatto che a Scampia è stato edificato un parco con degli enormi edifici che sono stati soprannominati "le vele" per la loro forma particolare; puoi vedere delle immagini [qui](https://www.google.it/search?q=le%20vele%20di%20scampia&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0zpmFxIDUAhVoLMAKHV3zASYQ_AUICigB&biw=1252&bih=556).

Answer (score -1):

È una figura retorica. A Scampia c'è un grattacielo famoso chiamato "Vele" quindi dice veleggiare per dire che svetta in mezzo agli altri edifici come una barca a vela in mezzo al mare.

Comment: Benvenuto! L'argomento è già esposto nell'altra risposta.